# Impossible to use two HDMI displays with one Thunderbolt 2 connector?

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

So I have an old MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014) and by reading the official Apple support page I've concluded that it is not possible to connect two (non-thunderbolt) screens through the single mini-DisplayPort. I'm not quite sure about the reason, as it seems that this mode of operation (mDP to two independent HDMI screens) is supported by Windows devices.

I am aware of the fact that I can connect two screens featuring thunderbolt-ports in series to achieve the same result, but I need two independent HDMI streams from the computer. Why can this not be achieved (or if so how)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two displays from one DisplayPort connection requires "multi-stream transport", and Apple does not support this.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Multi-Stream_Transport

There are video adapters from DisplayPort to two HDMI ports, and these would be supported by Windows and Linux but not on macOS.  I've come across people on the internet that claimed getting two displays from one port on Apple computers running macOS but it does seem quite clear that Apple does not support this function.  Without any official support for this your chances of it working consistently for you are slim.

The hardware in Apple computers is capable of supporting MST, so that's not stopping you.  This is proven quite clearly with people booting Windows or Linux on their Apple computers and getting MST adapters and displays to work.  Apple did not include support for MST in their OS or drivers.  We can all speculate as to why.  To get this working would involve some "hack" so there is no simple answer to your question other than it won't work.

So, yes, this is supported in Windows and if you boot your 2014 vintage Mac with Windows it would take only a MST DisplayPort to dual HDMI adapter to do as you wish.  Assuming you wish to run macOS on your Mac computer then you will not get it working, or rather your chances are pretty slim.